# Can you improve compression of multiple similar songs?

Tags: music, compression, ideas, optimizations

You probably heared of `tar`. It combines multiple files/directories into a single archive. After that one can compress this archive with `gzip`, `zstd`, `xz`, etc. If compressing similar files, the compression achieved by `tar.gz` will be better than of `.zip`. That's because `.zip` compresses each file separately, while `.tar.gz` compresses the whole `.tar` file.

So I've got an idea: suppose there are multiple similar songs, maybe from the same band or album. Would applying the same principle improve compression of the songs? If yes, then how much lossy vs. lossless algorithms would benefit from the technique?

P. S. I'm interested in audio codecs, but not familiar with codecs' internals, so this idea may sound ridiculous to the experts.

Comment: This sounds more like a data query than a sound design issue. Can you confirm if you're talking about data compression (reducing file size) or audio compression (reducing dynamic range)?

Comment: This question is based on a misunderstanding of compression (audio) vs compression (data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`gzip`, `zip` and other such encoding typically use repetition patterns to reduce the size (encoded properly, « copy the previous -20 to -10 characters » is more compact than the 10 bytes it represents), and Huffman coding (like in Morse alphabet, `.` is rather short and represents `E` the most common character).

Audio file compression doesn’t work like this. With MP3, there is a first pass of amplitude/frequency analysis (Fourier transform if you prefer), then each amplitude is coded with a variable precision. If coded with 6 bits because of the masking of a neighbour frequency, that makes 10 bits (16-6) saved… there are no repetition involved.

With lossless compression, the compressor takes into account that we can guess by extrapolation the next sample at each moment. Then it just code the error (anticipated sample - actual sample) if the extrapolation is wrong. No repetition too.

The experiment could be interesting. If a format includes an Huffman table, having a single file could save the space of the Huffman table. But if the Huffman table is fixed, inside the compressor/decompressor, there is nothing to save excepted a very light header (number of channels, format…)

Answer (score 1):

Audio data compression uses methods of essentially 'hiding' parts it calculates you can't hear, or notice if they're missing.
This can only be done 'in the moment'. You can't generalise over a larger time-frame.

Audio is compressed to smaller files by throwing away more of what you can't hear… down to the point you can really hear it, depending on what is considered 'important' to the delivery medium. Audio for a telephone voice transmission can be compressed a lot harder than that for hifi listening, because the level of 'acceptable' for a phone call has always been more compromised sonically.

You may have already noticed methods for regular data compression just don't work on audio files, the level of entropy is too high for them to be successful.